# How to discover which spring jar includes a spring package and class?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am upgrading the libraries on a system and am implementing spring boot. But, there are some dependencies that have to be added over and above the spring boot starters, and some of these are Spring classes.

How can I tell which library a package and class is coming from? The documentation for the class does not seem to provide this...

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding correctly, what i do is looking for [Compile Dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.3.0.RELEASE) in the maven repos.